# Read application/x-gzip InputStreamHi

Tags: java, gzip, inputstream

I want to read a file I get from a site. The site returns a content with the type of: "application/x-gzip".

InputStream ot GZIPInputStream don't work for me.
InputStream writes the output file not right, because than I read it as binary, and the file is not encoded well.
When I'm trying to create new GZIPInputStream base on the stream I'm getting an exception.

So, How do I read such thing?

Thanks.

Comment: "I read it as binary, and the file is not encoded well." - what does that mean? A gzip stream is binary data and you should handle it as such. Please post the exception when using the GZIPInputStream.

Comment: The file is in Hebrew and when read it with InputStream it don't read well.

Comment: The exception is: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format